# Smart GWT or ext GWT or Vaadin for Google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, smartgwt, vaadin

I have my back end on the Google app engine. Now I need a RIA on top of it. What should be my option?
  Smart GWT?
  Ext   GWT?
or Vaadin?

or if any of you know any other RIA UI tecnology other than JSF and Flex, pls let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same need: evaluating SmartGWT and Vaadin for RIA application hosted on GAE.

Comparing them so far I think **SmartGWT** is really faster and richer, because all GUI logic is compiled to javascript and they request server-side very lazily, only if client needs new data which were not loaded to browser before +some flexible caching stuff and so on.
And richer as SmartGWT ships more widgets.

But you have to implement all server-side stuff by yourself (or buy licence), it's a main disadvantage as you have to reimplement their proprietary DataSource protocols which most data-binding gui elements are build on.

Another disadvantage - first page loading takes a long time as there are a lot of static resources and compiled javascript stuff.

**Vaadin** uses quite an opposite way - you write all your business code on server-side with fully functional java and compose your GUI from predefined elements (with javascript already compiled for them).

The main difference is that it generated GUI and process most of browser events on a server side! So any action in browser that changes GUI state, like clicking to grid cell, button or tab - generates special request to the server-side and getting an aswer like that:

```
for(;;);[{"changes":[["change",{"format": "uidl","pid": "PID168"},["14",{"id": "PID168","width": "100.0%"},"Selected: [AS]"]]], "meta" : {}, "resources" : {}, "locales":[]}]
```

that indicates how GUI should be updated. So Vaadin gives you a full java support for your GUI logic, but you pay for that by processing all gui events on the server-side.

Thus I think **Vaadin is more suitable for Intranet and takes less time to develop your app while SmartGWT is better for more complex GUI or unstable connections where additional roundtrips matter**.

p.s. for GAE I'd choose SmartGWT as GAE has limits with server request number, bandwidth etc.

Comment: This is a fairly balanced answer, except that, on an intranet, Vaadin's server traffic is still not acceptable for use cases where you need logic to run on every mouse movement (custom drag and drop) or every keystroke (rapid data entry).  These are increasingly common scenarios.  Vaadin also requires a *lot* more server resources (all GUI state held on server; SmartGWT has none).  Finally, SmartGWT can contact existing services without need to implement our protocol, and if you use the commercial version, you integrate in Java (no REST server to implement).

Comment: thanks for clarification, what are examples of existing services which SmartGwt can contact with out of box?

Comment: Generally anything that returns JSON or XML.  This example: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#xpath_xml_integration_category  .. shows binding to an XML format like what a JAX-RS service might return.  However note we don't recommend binding to generated services as a general approach, for very good reasons (see http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=8159#aExistingRest).

Comment: Also note, our 'proprietary' REST protocol isn't really any more proprietary than a JAX-RS generated service, which is going to be different every time based on whatever API it is generated from.  There is currently no standard in this area to rally around, so we provided a 'cookbook' REST protocol that handles all enterprise needs (batch operations, complex criteria, etc).  And again, with the commercial version you can just return Java beans directly in server code, or skip the whole process since SQL/JPA/Hibernate is built-in.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged this question with GAE (Google App Engine).  Vaadin has a terrible drawback there: it pretty much requires sticky sessions for adequate performance, background here:

http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/6349

.. but GAE does not support sticky sessions and never will.  Bug closed WontFix here:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1320

Neither GXT nor SmartGWT require sticky sessions and neither suffers from the issue discussed on Vaadin.com.  Full disclosure: I'm the CTO of the company that makes SmartGWT.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe just plain GWT. Or maybe just HTML ;-) What are your needs? What does your application do?

Comment: I think _RIA on top of GAE_ is itself quite an outstanding task.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using plain GWT and I like very much the flexibility and the performance. On the other side, I miss a bit of organization of the information. Much of the topics are covered in scattered post in several forums and a lot of hacking is needed. IMHO there is not a clear concept to where this framework is going, and for what use.

On the other side, Vaadin , which I have tested, has very interesting features, works very well righ out of the box, and is free, but the supporting community is much smaller.

Flex looks very oriented to content display, while GWT, and its heirs (SmartGWT, Vaadin, ..) seems to preval for business-like applications.

Comment: We try to provide the best possible community support for Vaadin, and we currently have ~40 Vaadin Ltd employees (all programmers) reading and answering questions on our forum. Have you ran into any questions on the forum that did not get quickly resolved?

Comment: Didn't want to misvaluate your good work. The fact is that a lot of beginner questions are self-answered in the Vaadin forum. But the truth is that GWT community is larger, compare number of results for any google search related to any of the frameworks.

Comment: Actually, that's not really true.  Searching on "GWT" is going to hit a bunch of Vaadin, SmartGWT and GXT info too.  Both SmartGWT and Vaadin have more activity on their forums than exists on the core GWT forums, and in both cases, I would say the traffic is higher quality.